# Contact Tab List View Does Not Show for Some Users when a Picklist is Added

Tags: lightning, picklist, list-view, lightninglistview

I have a Contact Tab List View, and when I add a picklist or multi-select picklist to the view, I get an error.

Here is what the list view looks like before I add a picklist:
[image: Before Picklist]

Once I add the picklist, it won't appear in the columns or no columns appear if I refreshed the page, and I get this message instead:
[image: Error Message]

When I look at these views with an admin, I do see the picklist columns:
[image]

The user has read and edit access to the picklist, granted to the profile and to the assigned permission set.

What am I missing, and how can I get this to work for my end users?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try steps mentioned (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335525&type=1)

Comment: Hi @Vinay - I did, and they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that when I removed the record type filter from the list view, it would start showing the picklist column.  It was necessary to have the record type filter, so it didn't help to just remove the filter.

I reached out to Salesforce's support for this, and they found that one of the SObjects for the profile with the problem didn't have an assigned page layout - In this case, it was the Event.

Although the Event's fields were not on the list view, nor was any formula field using fields from the Event, it was preventing the list view from showing when I added a record type filter.

Once I assigned the page layouts for the Event, the list views started working.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue. Tried your solution and unfortunately that didn't do it for me, so I also submitted a case with SF Support and this is what they responded, which did the trick in my case:

"While investigating I found that the affected users do not have any assigned global publisher layout. The issue might be happen due to this as well.

Can you please check the below step and assign the layout and check the list view is showing data or not?

For the Global Publisher Layout, go to:
Setup > User Interface > Global Actions > Publisher Layouts > check the layout assignments and make sure it does not say 'Not Assigned' for the affected profile."

Just thought I'd add another answer for anyone finding this in the future.